# How to fetch data from AngularJS to Python Script

Tags: angularjs, python-2.7

I am new for python so if you can help me to solve my problem. I want fetch Username and Password 
from angularjs to python script In my python script then what mechanism i want to follow to achieve this gole.

---

html code

```
<form  action="" method="post" id="homeTitle">
<table width="20%">
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><label class='lblUserEmail'>
Email</label></td><td align='center'>
<input id='Email' type='text' style='background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);' ng-model='Email'>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<label class='lblPassword'>Password</label></td>
<td align='center'><input id='password' type='password'style='background-color: rgb(250, 255, 189);' ng-model='password'>
</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td align='right'>
<button id='Login' name='Login' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="checkLogin()">
Login
</button>
</td> 
</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</form>
```

---

angularjs code

```
$http.post("/python/index.py/", user_data)
                .success(function(response) {
                    //console.log(response);
                    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + response.token;

                    // $rootScope.toke = response.token;
                    // console.log($rootScope.toke);
                    //$location.path("/dashboard");
                    var toke = response.token;

                    //console.log(toke);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:login-confirmed',toke);

                jQuery("#loginBox").slideUp(function(){jQuery('#blanket').css({'display':'none'});});
                jQuery('#homeTitle').css({'display':'none'});
                jQuery(".bottomImages").slideDown();
        });     
    };
```

---

Iam not using Django Python frame work. I am trying to create ma own frame work using wsgi and python so. 
Help me to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have tagged this post as Django but have not used Django yet. I suggest that you read the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) and solve this. [Part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/) covers how you can create a simple form in Django, like yours.

In simple terms, your problem is that you have created the frontend to show the form but do not have a backend to take action on the form once it gets submitted. You can use any server based web frameworks like Flask, Pyramid or even Node.js for this.